# update specific row based on user selection using PDO via php issue

Tags: php

I am trying to update my sql table based off user input. So the user picks from a select list the column they want to update. Then they enter the data from the row and then what they want to update that with. so say the pick column teamname, the would then enter the team name they want to change via text box and then via another textbox enter the new name. Thats what Im trying to get to happen anyways.

I tried to copy and paste my code from where the user deletes data and modify it. I have tried a couple different things, the first thing I tried gave me this error:

> UPDATE teams SET rockets = :value1 WHERE teamname = rockets
>   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'rockets' in 'where clause'

My sql statement looked like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE teams SET $selectData = :value1  WHERE $columnSelect = $selectData";
```

Then, I tried to do something like this:

entire code below, as stated above I have tried a couple different thigns with the `$sql` variable:

**php**

```
<?php

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){ 

        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "";
        $columnSelect = $_POST['selectColumn2'];
        $selectData = $_POST['selectData'];
        $updateData = $_POST['updateData'];

        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            // sql to delete a record
            $sql = "UPDATE teams SET :value1 = :value2  WHERE $columnSelect = :value1";

            // use exec() because no results are returned
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(array(':value1'=>$selectData, ':value2'=>$updateData));
            if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                echo 'Updated '.$stmt->rowCount().' rows';
            } else {
                echo 'No rows updated';
                }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
            {
            echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
            }

        $conn = null;
    }
?>
```

**html**

```
        <form method='post' action='addData.php'>
            Select a column name, then enter which data to update.
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for='option2'>
                <select name='selectColumn2'>
                    <option value='teamname' id='team2'>teamname</option>
                    <option value='city' id='city2'>city</option>
                    <option value='bestplayer' id='best2'>bestplayer</option>
                    <option value='yearformed' id='year2'>year</option>
                    <option value='website' id='website2'>website</option>
                </select>
            </label>    
            <label for='option2'>
                select data to change: <input type='text' name='selectData'>
                enter new data: <input type='text' name='updateData'>
            </label>
            <br><br>
            <input type='submit' value='Submit New Entry'>
        </form>
```

Basically what I what to do is take `$columnSelect`, find `$selectData` in that column and replace it with `$updateData` using the PDO method. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Column names and table names can not be parameterized (to my knowledge). You have to find a different way to filter user input when it comes to those elements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your query like this,

```
$sql = "UPDATE teams SET `$selectData` = ':value1'  WHERE `$columnSelect` = '$selectData'";
```

Add single quotes for string values while inserting or updating. And addd backtics for the table name or column names.

**EDIT**

```
$sql = "UPDATE teams SET `$columnSelect` = ':value1'  WHERE `$columnSelect` = '$selectData'";
```

Comment: i may have done something wrong, UPDATE teams SET `rockets` = ':value1' WHERE `teamname` = 'rockets'
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'rockets' in 'field list'.......... I 100% have a row with data 'rockets' under column teamname.... since rockets isnt a column name just the row i want to update should i leave out the backtics....

Comment: do you have a column name by `rockets` in your table??

Comment: no i have a column called teamname with 4 rows, the first row is the team/data 'rockets'..... so the column name would be teamname, the data i want to update would be 'rockets' updated to rangers.  in this case that would be $columnSelect for column name, $selectData for rockets, and the variable $updateData for rangers. I want to update 'rockets' to 'rangers' in column 'teamname

Comment: according to your query, you shud have a column by name `rockets`.

Comment: I have something backwards then

Comment: ok new issue, instead of using the data input from user its just placing ':value1' in the row, i have the exec(array()) function inplace to assigned a string to the 'value1' or do i not?

Comment: Glad it helped you. Consider accepting and upvoting the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:    `UPDATE teams SET $columnSelect = :value1 WHERE $columnSelect = $selectData`